# What is Laravel QB update with Join as 'select' correct syntax?

Tags: php, laravel

I have correct MySQL query that works fine and I tried to push it into Laravel Query Builder syntax, but not understand some little part.

I tried to write QB expression (see below).

It's my SQL query:

```
    update LOW_PRIORITY zoho_contacts z
    inner join
    (select contactid,  min(due_date) as mini_date
    from zoho_invoices
    where deleted_at is null and due_date is not null and summa_oplaty > 0
    group by contactid ) co using (contactid)
    set z.data_pervoy_pokupki = co.mini_date
    where z.contactid = co.contactid AND z.data_pervoy_pokupki IS null
```

It's my QB query:

```
        DB::table('zoho_contacts z')
            ->join(DB::table('zoho_invoices')
            ->select(DB::raw('contactid,  min(due_date) as mini_date'))
            ->whereNull('deleted_at')
            ->whereNotNull('due_date')
            ->where('summa_oplaty', '>', 0)
            ->groupBy('contactid') . ' as co', 'z.contactid', 'co.contactid' )
        ->update(['z.data_pervoy_pokupki' => 'co.mini_date'])
        ->where('z.contactid', 'co.contactid')
        ->whereNull('z.data_pervoy_pokupki');

        dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

this my expression produces error

```
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string
```

pointing to string

```
->groupBy('contactid') . ' as co', 'z.contactid', 'co.contactid' )
```

I suggest that error is ' as co' because it placed in not proper place.
I need this alias because I have this

```
->where('z.contactid', 'co.contactid')
```

**How can I to name result of query nested into Join?**

```
->select(DB::raw('contactid,  min(due_date) as mini_date'))
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->whereNotNull('due_date')
    ->where('summa_oplaty', '>', 0)
    ->groupBy('contactid') . ' as co', 'z.contactid', 'co.contactid'
```

Comment: When I moved 'co' to 'join' like this, 
`->join(DB::table('zoho_invoices co') ` 
I got another error that is like previous 
`In Grammar.php line 36:
  Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string `

Comment: Also, the keyword 'AS' not helps `->join(DB::table('zoho_invoices AS co') ` - the same error.

Answer (score 0):

check this if it is work:

```
  DB::table('zoho_contacts z')
        ->join(DB::raw("(select contactid,  min(due_date) as mini_date from zoho_invoices
        where deleted_at is null and due_date is not null and summa_oplaty > 0
        group by contactid ) co"),"z.contactid'","=","co.contactid")
        ->where('z.contactid', 'co.contactid')
        ->whereNull('z.data_pervoy_pokupki')
        ->update(['z.data_pervoy_pokupki' => 'co.mini_date']) ;
```

Comment: Osama, thank you!
it works!
I pushed your answer 'up' (or +1) but my mention not yet visible here. Also, when I try to use '@' with your name it not acts :(

Comment: For completely resolve this task, I need one more solution.
In original query there is this `update LOW_PRIORITY zoho_contacts z` - I mean 'LOW_PRIORITY'. 
How can I implement that 'key'?